# How to use object property with class in OWL API?

Tags: java, owl, protege, owl-api

I'm currently using OWL API and Protege, and I have a problem, because Protege allows me to do something like this:

[image]

This is pizza ontology. I have individual Americana, and I add "hasBase DeepPanBase" (which is called in WebProtege as Relationship, in desktop version it is placed in Types), where hasBase is object property and DeepPanBase is class.

Problem is that in OWL API I have function getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom, but it works for object property and two individuals.

Is there a way to copy Protege approach and use class, or at least do some static individual? Or should I jst do another individual for each scenario and that's it?

Comment: I don't know hat you're asking. Do you just want to get the type of the individual which is a complex class expression via OWL API?

Answer (score 1):

The Types panel in Protégé refers to classes and the expression you see, with a qualifier, an object property and a class is a class expression (for example, an existential or universal restriction). These are represented as class assertions or subclass assertions (depending whether the subject is an individual - class assertion - or you're declaring a superclass for a class).

For OWLAPI introduction: the most recent tutorial is linked here https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Tutorial:-A-starter's-starter

The wiki has a lot more docs.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand much better what it is, but still I don't see how to do something like this in Java. Do you happen to know about some helpful function in OWL API?